# iPhone red circular button with 'x'

Tags: iphone

Probably a silly question here but I have been trying to find this for about an hour now. How do I create the circular red button with an 'x' that appears when navigating pages in safari for example. And is there an 'official' name of such a button type?

[Screenshot](http://www.iphonity.com/pictures/3.0-1.png)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a button eIther from scratch or from the screenshot in an Image editor like photoshop and then import it into your project and set a button's image to the name of the image. There is no official name for this button and you can't add it to your app using a key or special method.

Comment: Thanks! I was sadly reaching that conclusion.